# PHP $_POST error

Tags: php, forms, post, undefined

I'm getting the following error with $_POST['str']:

> Notice: Undefined index: str in C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-5.3.8.0\www\strrev.php on line 12

I spent too much time to find an answer for this but no luck! 
Please take a look at the code and let me know what's wrong with it?

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <?php 
    if (trim($_POST['str'])) {
      $str = $_POST['str'];
  $len = strlen($str);
      for($i=($len-1); $i>=0;$i--) {
      echo $str[$i];
      } 
} else {
  ?>
<form method="post" action="">
    <input type="text" name="str" />
    <input type="button" name="submit" value="Reverse" />
    </form>
    <?php
  }
  ?>
</body>
</html>
```

It shows the text field and Reverse button beside the error.
And also when I push the button nothing will happens.

Comment: isn't the error slef-explanatory ? you try to access an undefined index of the $_POST array.. maybe because you didn't POST anything yet ? Go take a look at the "isset" php function

Answer (score 7):

Change `if (trim($_POST['str']))` to `if (!empty($_POST['str']))`

Your `if` statement is trying to trim an array index that does not exist, hence the error.  You must check if your index exists first.

In case anyone is wondering - I used `empty` instead of `isset` as the OP, by using `trim`, implied (or at least, I inferred from this) that a properly set `$_POST['str']` containing an empty string was unacceptable.  This won't fix the case where `$_POST['str']` contains a bunch of spaces, however.

Answer (score 0):

You're not checking if a POST has actually occured:

```
<html>
...
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
   if ($_POST yada yada yada) {
       ...
   }
}
?>

<form action="" method="POST">
...
</form>

...

</html>
```

Comment: This is incorrect, no need to do that, isset and empty will do just fine.

Comment: @Bot, no, it is *not* incorrect. Just downvoting Marc's because he downvoted yours is not fair. Get your facts right first.

Comment: @phant0m it is incorrect. you are checking if post was done (isn't needed) you are then doing an `if ($_POST yada yada yada)` (what is that yada yada yada). this still wouldn't fix his error message. so it is indeed incorrect. Also he removed his downvote. I am downvoting because it is wrong and will not resolve the OP's issue.

Comment: @bot: it's a dual-purpose form. first time requested via GET to show the form, yet the OP is testing for values in $_POST. since a POST didn't occur, $_POST will be completely empty, and hence the undefined index warning. add the if() wrapper to check if a POST has occured will solve the warning, since the check code only runs when a POST really did occur. Of course, the check should STILL have isset/empty in case the form field isn't present/renamed/whatever.

Comment: @MarcB yes your post check will check if the call was a  POST but he is receiving this warning also because `str` is not provided, On initial page load, `str` hasn't been submitted. Should the form get submitted without passing in `str` this error will still occur.

Comment: @bot: yes, but 'str' is provided, with that particular code, **IF** a post was performed. Bah, but who cares. it's a stupid argument.

Comment: you are correct, this code above (- the yada yada yada, don't know what that is) would work for the answer above, however it would be a localized answer.) I will remove my downvote, if you remove the yada, yada, yada, since it would resolve the issue for the OP (assuming he didn't create psudo code / html)

Comment: I am downvoting this for one reason. No yada yada before accessing the index. A comment has been given for clarification but taking the only answer into account, it is incomplete. (even including yada yada part).

Comment: Upvoting because it's the only answer that do a general POST check (is something post) before checking a specific field (is a field is in the POST)

Comment: @Bixi you are missing the point `isset($_POST['str'])` and `!empty($_POST['str'])` do this AND check for the field.

Comment: @MarcB You can check if the Request Method is a post, but you still have to run isset on $_POST['str']  AND you aren't required to check Request Method.

Answer (score 0):

$str is not necessarily an array.  In order to loop through it, it needs to be an array.
It's just copying that value from $_POST['str'], so when you do the post either

Make sure it's an array with

```
if (is_array($str))
```

Comment: This is a good point, however, this wouldn't solve the error. Very good for the OP to note though. Since `str` is an input textbox it actually wouldn't be an array but a string.